# Unable to pageup and pagedown in Atom Editor OSX

Tags: macos, github, editor, text-editor, atom-editor

I'm revisiting the latest version of Atom to see if it's a contender for my go-to text editor (currently Sublime Text).

However it seems I'm unable to pageup or pagedown when in the text editor body of Atom.  The pageup and pagedown keys work fine when scrolling through the Settings > Settinsg or Settings > Keybindings pages, but no response when in the main editor window.

I'm using Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.2 with Atom 1.8.0 and am using an external PC style keyboard. I also use Karabiner keymapping app but am not sure that's related.

Has anyone come across this? How do I map pageup/pagedown correctly? Is there any way in Atom to report back the keystroke it's receiving when I press a key?

Thanks.

Comment: My work laptop has the same Atom and OS and the page up/down is working fine inside the main Atom editor window for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Keybinding Resolver to determine what keystrokes were being receieved when I clicked pageup and pagedown.

For some reason I've yet to determine, it was being received as alt+pageup and alt+pagedown.

Quick fix was just to add the following to the keymap.cson:

```
'body':
  'alt-pageup': 'core:page-up'
  'alt-pagedown': 'core:page-down'
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution didn't work for me for Atom for mac. But when I pasted following block in keymap.cson, I am able to use alt+up as page up and alt+down as page down.

'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-up': 'core:page-up'
  'alt-down': 'core:page-down'